# Why MS Virtual PC has the limitation about 16 bits per pixel? Is it possible to hack this up to 24/32 bpp?

Tags: virtualization, settings, color

I don't get it. Why did they set such limitation? Just want to know the reason.
Maybe it can be hacked somehow?

- **Virtual PC version**: latest Windows Virtual PC
- **Host OS**: Windows 7 x64
- **Guest OS**: Windows XP Professional

Comment: MS Virtual PC Version? Host OS Version? Virtual Guest OS Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual machine model they use doesn't have a large enough frame buffer and the paravirtualised video driver knows this. There may be a hack but it would risk VM instability, personally I'd just pick up one of the other virtualisation solutions such as virtualbox, vmware workstation/server etc.

Comment: What's the best choice for migration on your opinion?

Comment: I'm a VMWare-guy myself, you might even be able to open up the VirtualPC file itself actually.